# Very Simple "Random Movie Windows App" which is getting data from Trakt.tv Watchlist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to do a simple windows app for picking a random movie from my trakt.tv watchlist, I used tkinter for a basic gui, then use random funciton to choice a movie from a txt file, then with trakt library fucntion I get my watch list from trakt and record it as a txt for random choice, define a function to one of my button to pick a random movie from there and show it in text box. It's working in that way but now I want to add overview, rating, year information related to the random movie, it is working good for just "some titles" but some movies get following error message; "trakt.errors.NotFoundException: Not Found - method exists, but no record found"

I think some movie's names can't get direct result from trakt.tv, so what could be solution for that? For example; can I get trakt_id from a watchlist and use it for all other information and how? I check library files but it seems get the info directly user list website and I couldn't figure out how can I get any other information from there.
Also how can I add a random fanart under the buttons related to movie which choiced by random?

Sorry my English and if I can't explain my questions well :)

My code is below;

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import random
from tkinter import *
from trakt import init
from trakt.users import User
from trakt.movies import Movie
import tkinter as tk

### For Trakt.tv Authorize and Save It
### init('myusername', store=True)

my = User('username') ## Must be your username
watchlist = my.watchlist_movies
f=open("watchmovies.txt","w", encoding='utf-8')
f.write(str(watchlist))
f.close()

# TXT DOSYASINI DÜZENLEME
# Read in the file
with open('watchmovies.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('[', '')
filedata = filedata.replace(']', '')
# Write the file out again
with open('watchmovies.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
# New Line for Commas
f1=open("watchmovies.txt","r+")
input=f1.read()
print(input)
input=input.replace('<Movie>:','\n')
input=input.replace(',','')
f2=open("watchmovies.txt","w+")
f2.write(input)
f1.close()
f2.close()

# Pencere oluşturma
window = Tk()
window.title("Pick A Movie For Me")
window.geometry("300x500")
window.configure(background='black')

# Yazı Alanı oluşturma
T = Text(window, height=15, width=40, wrap = WORD)
T.configure(background='orange')
T.pack()

# Random bilgi için kaynak dosyası
lines = open('watchmovies.txt').read().splitlines()

# Buton işlemi
def callback():
    myline = random.choice(lines)
    print(myline)
    myline2 = Movie(str(myline))
    yeary = str(myline2.year)
    ratingy = str(myline2.rating)[:4]
    overviewy = str(myline2.overview)
    T.delete('1.0', END)
    showline= "\n" + myline + " " + ratingy + "\n" + yeary  + "\n" + "\n" + overviewy
    T.insert("1.0", showline)
    T.tag_add('center', "1.0", "end")
    T.tag_configure("center", justify='center', font='Calibri 11 bold')

# Butonlar
b = Button(window, text="Good Luck!", command=callback)
b.configure(background='black', foreground='white')
b.pack()
c = Button(window, text="Close", command=window.quit)
c.configure(background='black', foreground='white')
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Code of the final situation after I handled everything:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import random
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from trakt import init
from trakt.users import User
from trakt.movies import Movie
from IMDBAPI import IMDB
from tmdbv3api import TMDb
from tmdbv3api import Movie
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO

## FOR IMDB, TMDB, TRAKT API 
imdb = IMDB()
tmdb = TMDb()
tmdb.api_key = '<YOUR_TMDB_API_KEY>'
my = User('<YOUR_TRAKT_USER_NAME>')

## Trakt.tv Watchlist 
watchlist = my.watchlist_movies
f=open("watchmovies.txt","w", encoding='utf-8')
f.write(str(watchlist))
f.close()

# TXT FILE
# Read in the file
with open('watchmovies.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('[', '')
filedata = filedata.replace(']', '')
# Write the file out again
with open('watchmovies.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
# New Line for Commas
f1=open("watchmovies.txt","r+")
input=f1.read()
print(input)
input=input.replace('<Movie>:','\n')
input=input.replace(',','')
f2=open("watchmovies.txt","w+")
f2.write(input)
f1.close()
f2.close()

# File for Random 
lines = open('watchmovies.txt').read().splitlines()

# Button Functions
def callback():
    ### TEXT INFOS
    myline = str(random.choice(lines))
    imdbtt = IMDB.getIdFromName(myline)
    ratingy = imdb.getRatingByImdbId(imdbtt)
    summary = imdb.getSummaryByImdbId(imdbtt)
    query_url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&query='
    ## ARRANGMENTS FOR TMDB IMAGE SEARCH
    myline2 = myline.replace(' ', '%20')
    moviename = myline2
    title2 = query_url + moviename
    link = title2
    f = urlopen(link)
    myfile = f.read()
    f = open("posterurl.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(str(myfile))
    f.close()
    f3 = open("posterurl.txt", "r+")
    input = f3.read()
    input = input.replace('\\/', '\n')
    input = input.replace('jpg"', 'jpg\n')
    f4 = open("posterurl.txt", "w+")
    f4.write(input)
    f3.close()
    f4.close()
    file = open("posterurl.txt", "r")
    posterdata = file.readlines()
    posterurl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/' + posterdata[1]
    ##TEXT SETTINGS
    global showline
    showline = "\n" + myline + "\n" + ratingy + "\n"
    global showline2
    showline2 = "\n" + summary
    ## GETTING IMAGE URL
    URL = posterurl
    u = urlopen(URL)
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    global photo
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

# Actions to GUI
def guishow():
    ##IMAGE TO GUI
    global window2
    window2.pack_forget()
    window2 = tk.Label(image=photo)
    window2.image = photo
    window2.pack()
    ## TEXTS TO GUI
    T.delete('1.0', END)
    T.insert("1.0", showline)
    T.tag_add('center', "1.0", "end")
    T.tag_configure("center", justify='center', font='Calibri 11 bold')
    T2.delete('1.0', END)
    T2.insert("1.0", showline2)
    T2.tag_add('center', "1.0", "end")
    T2.tag_configure("center", justify='center', font='Calibri 10 bold')

# GUI: MAIN WINDOW
window = Tk()
window.title("Pick A Movie For Me")
window.geometry("300x600")
window.configure(background='black')
window2 = Frame(window)
window2.pack(side="bottom", expand=True, fill="both")
window2.configure(background='black')

# GUI: TEXT AREA
T = Text(window, height=5, width=40, wrap = WORD)
T.configure(background='darkgray')
T.pack()

# GUI: TEXT AREA 2
T2 = Text(window, height=8, width=40, wrap = WORD)
T2.configure(background='gray')
T2.pack()

## BUTTON FUNCTIONS MERGING
def buttoncase():
     callback()
     guishow()

# BUTTONS
b = Button(window, text="Good Luck!", command=buttoncase)
b.configure(background='black', foreground='white')
b.pack()
c = Button(window, text="Close", command=window.quit)
c.configure(background='black', foreground='white')
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your tags because your question focuses on the trakt modul not tkinter nor random. ^^

Comment: Thank you for warning, unfortunately I cannot add trakt tag because it's not existent yet I think. I removed random tag but keep tkinter because one of my question is related to adding image to GUI.

Comment: Oh. I missed the second question. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding an image you need to create an instance of  `PhotoImage` with the file path to your picture. Then when you want to map the picture you have several options of widgets which could contain images but I'd recommend using Label in this case. So create an instance of `Label` with the keywords you like and set `image=<your image variable>`. Make sure you don't just have the PhotoImage instance on a temporary variable. So i.e. when you are doing all this inside a class you can make the PhotoImage variable a class variable. Otherwise, you can make it a sub variable of your Label widget. In the end, it is your own choice. For your images you're then limited to .png, .pkg, .gif (not moving as far as I know) and a bit more (look that up at effbot.org). You can also use .bmp but then you will need to use `BitmapImage` instead of `PhotoImage`. A little Example:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label,PhotoImage #Python 3.x -> replace 'tkinter' with 'Tkinter' in Python 2.x

root=Tk()
img=PhotoImage(file='yourpath/Image.png')
label=Label(root,image=img)
label.pack()
label.image=img #if not in a class
#self.image=img #if in a class
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I think I could manage all with your help for image. About trakt issue I used IMDBAPI library after get the names from trakt it handles rest and I am getting image's url from TMDB api. Maybe not perfect way but it's working :)

Comment: My code was too long for comment area :D so I added final version of my code to first entry maybe anyone can get something in future..

Comment: Maybe two additions to your code there: 1) You don't need to unmap and remap the Frame window2 when assigning the Label with the image. ^^  2) Althought it's not technically nessesary always give a tkinter widget a master widget because otherwise tkinter have to assign it itseld wich is needs more processing power after all. ^^

Comment: Thanks for additions, that's just a learning project for me to understand basic things, and I know it's way more heavy than should be which an app has that simple task :) and now I will try to make a more handsome gui and code for this app to improve myself and try to make it more clearly with less code as less as I can :) but about "unmap and remap" thing, actually it is working to clear area for new photo when I click to button again for new result and if I don't use that lines old photo just stayed and new one getting under it I don't know why, so..

Comment: Ah me and my half way reading... I just saw that you reassign window2 to a new Label. Ok so what happens there is that you might have replaced where the pointer "window2" (Yeah in python variables are actually all just pointers) points to. But the old widget is still there, there is just no variable in python pointing to it. But in the underlaying tcl interpreter there is (and you could see it by looking up the <master>.children dictionary). So what you actually wanna do instead of ```window2.pack_forget()``` is ```window2.destroy()``` which completely removes the old Label with the old image.

Comment: I uploaded the final version to github, https://github.com/Lunedor/RandomWithTrakt